# SQlite3: EDatabase Error - Query - Cannot perform this operation on a closed dataset

Tags: sql, database, delphi, sqlite, zeos

I am using SQLite3 and Zeoslib on Delphi 2010. The following code is supposed to traverse through records in a table and update fields. So, it is within a `while` loop checking on END OF FILE condition. However, it never breaks but continually looping forever crashing the program. I did find out that based on the SELECT statement one record is returned. Here is the code. Query is opened for SQL statement to execute. So, I don't know why it will say it is a closed dataset, unless `post` operation closes the query right after.

```
procedure TAlarmMgrDlg.Update(alarm:TAlarm);
begin
   DataModule1.AlarmQuery.Close;
   DataModule1.AlarmQuery.SQL.Clear;
   DataModule1.AlarmQuery.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM ALARMS');
   DataModule1.AlarmQuery.SQL.Add('WHERE TAGNAME = ''' + string(alarm.Tagname) + '''');
   DataModule1.AlarmQuery.SQL.Add('AND ALARM_NAME = ''' + string(alarm.Name) + '''');
   DataModule1.AlarmQuery.SQL.Add('AND ALARM_STATE = 2');

   DataModule1.AlarmQuery.Open;
   if not DataModule1.AlarmQuery.Isempty then
       DataModule1.AlarmQuery.First;

   while not DataModule1.AlarmQuery.EOF do
   begin
      DataModule1.AlarmQuery.Edit;
      DataModule1.AlarmQuery.FieldValues['ACKTIME'] := Now;
      DataModule1.AlarmQuery.FieldValues['ALARM_STATE'] := 1;
      if alarm.IsAutoAck then
         DataModule1.AlarmQuery.FieldValues['USER_ACK'] := 'AUTO'
      else
      begin
         if UserProfile = nil then
         begin
            if alarm.LogUserID = true then
            begin
                DataModule1.AlarmQuery.FieldValues['USER_ACK'] := ThisUserID;
            end
            else
            begin
                DataModule1.AlarmQuery.FieldValues['USER_ACK'] := 'No User';
            end;
         end
         else
         begin
             if alarm.LogUserID = true then
             begin
                DataModule1.AlarmQuery.FieldValues['USER_ACK'] := ThisUserID;
             end
             else
             begin
                DataModule1.AlarmQuery.FieldValues['USER_ACK'] := UserProfile.fName;
             end;
         end;
      end;
      DataModule1.AlarmQuery.Post;
   end;
end;
```

Here is how the DataModule is used to create the database:

```
  ZConnection1.Protocol:='sqlite-3';
  ZConnection1.Database:=basedir + 'alrmdata\alarms.db';
  ZConnection1.Connect;
  AlarmQuery.SQL.Add('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS alarms ');
  AlarmQuery.SQL.Add('(TAGNAME VARCHAR(16),');
  AlarmQuery.SQL.Add('ALARM_NAME VARCHAR(32),');
  AlarmQuery.SQL.Add('ALARM_GROUP INTEGER,');
  AlarmQuery.SQL.Add('ALARM_PRIORITY INTEGER,');
  AlarmQuery.SQL.Add('ALARM_TYPE INTEGER,');
  AlarmQuery.SQL.Add('ALARM_STATE INTEGER,');
  AlarmQuery.SQL.Add('ALARM_VALUE FLOAT,');
  AlarmQuery.SQL.Add('ALARM_LIMIT1 FLOAT,');
  AlarmQuery.SQL.Add('ALARM_LIMIT2 FLOAT,');
  AlarmQuery.SQL.Add('ALARMTIME DATETIME,');
  AlarmQuery.SQL.Add('ACKTIME DATETIME,');
  AlarmQuery.SQL.Add('NORMALTIME DATETIME,');
  AlarmQuery.SQL.Add('ALARM_MSG VARCHAR(32),');
  AlarmQuery.SQL.Add('USER_ACK VARCHAR(32))');
  AlarmQuery.ExecSQL;
  AlarmQuery.Close;
  ZConnection1.Disconnect;
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: There's no `Next` inside your `while` loop.

Comment: yep, Sorry I didn't completely copy the procedure.... it is there now...

Comment: @TLama I did try that and still the same result....Let me check again..

Comment: Um, no it's not. I make it a habit, every single time I type `while not DS.Eof do begin` and hit enter (at which point the IDE adds the `end`) to make the very next thing I type `DS.Next` just above that added `end`. Infinite loops are really annoying, and forgetting the `Next` in a `while not Eof` is very easy. In this case, you're just editing the same row over and over again with the same exact values. `Post` does not call `Close`, so the issue isn't there. What happens if you set a breakpoint on the `Post` line and evaluate the `AlarmQuery.Active` property?

Comment: @KenWhite I just added the line `DataModule1.AlarmQuery.Next;` still not working...

Comment: Try [`something like this`](http://pastebin.com/1F4j1LAc).

Comment: There is nothing in the code you posted that would cause the state to change from `dsEdit`. The only thing I see that's suspicious is the `ZConnection1.Disconnect` in your second code block; it seems strange to disconnect from the database. Your Update code does not reconnect.

Comment: @KenWhite That second block of code is executed when Datamodule is created. After that ZConnection does connect to the database somewhere else in the program before my Update procedure is called.

Comment: Then I'm afraid I can't help. As I said before, there is nothing in the entire block of code you posted that would take the state out of `dsEdit`.

Comment: @KenWhite I think you are right about missing `Next` at the end of the while loop. I also have another while loop in other area in my program without `Next`. I added next to both of them... Now it seems work fine. thank.

Comment: You should avoid this "golden ring" style *one query component to rule them all*. Instead build a query component for each aspect and just use it.